# The window.name property was not set because the target window belongs to a different domain

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-9, cross-domain

I am getting error in IE.

**DOM7004: The window.name property was not set because the target window belongs to a different domain.**

I searched in Google and didn't any good link to solve this

Can you please help to know why this error is coming and how to solve this issue.

Please Help

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should explain more what were you doing when you got this error.

Comment: don't know at what position that error is coming

actually i am using CSE Google(to get the Google content). Is that is a problem?

Comment: i am getting error in this js file

https://www.google.com/uds/api/search/1.0/c6de88f78fba657057a235c40805b4d0/default+en.I.js

Comment: should i ignore the error? or there is some method to over come from this error.

Comment: @Shekhar Please take a look at my another problem ,i think you can solve that one.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786966/ie-9-issue-showing-aborted-please-reply

Answer (score 0):

Check the privacy settings in IE.

I noticed that I had a problem with javascript not loading and it was only happening in IE. I got the same error that you have and changing the privacy settings made the error go away.

Comment: Hi bkerrigan, What would you changed privacy settings